# Calling Excel Macro through a bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, macros, command-prompt

I need to open multiple excel files(which contains a macro that runs as soon as it opens) through a bat file. It works when I type the line in the command prompt however, when I make the `.BAT`, it doesn't work correctly. the format I’m using is really just

```
START "Path\Excelfile.xlsm"

START "Path\Excelfile.xlsm"

START "Path\Excelfile.xlsm"
```

I'm fairly new to this so if any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generally:

START /D"path_to_program" program.exe "file_to_open_or_another_parameters"

in your case:

START /D"path_to_excel" excel.exe "Excelfile.xlsm"

my foolproof example (attested with PSPad, as I haven't excel installed):

start /D"C:\Program Files\PSPad editor" PSPad.exe "c:\temp\debug.txt"

Answer (score 0):

START needs a first parameter of a title name. Try:

```
START "" "Path\Excelfile.xlsm"
```

Edit: It doesn't *need* a first parameter of a title name, but if you give it a first parameter in quotes, it reads that as if you are trying to set a title name instead of a program to run, so you have to work around that.

See the help with `start /?` - the first optional parameter is a quoted window title.

```
C:\>start /?
Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.

START ["title"] [/D path] [/I] [/MIN] [/MAX] [/SEPARATE | /SHARED]
      [/LOW | /NORMAL | /HIGH | /REALTIME | /ABOVENORMAL | /BELOWNORMAL]
      [/NODE <NUMA node>] [/AFFINITY <hex affinity mask>] [/WAIT] [/B]
      [command/program] [parameters]

    "title"     Title to display in window title bar.
```